# Font lock of inline code in org-mode?

Tags: org-export, latex, org-babel, font-lock

When using org-mode as a front-end to LaTeX, I'm making heavy use of inline code like `@@latex:\textit{something italic}@@`. Right now, this is mainly displayed as normal text (with proportional font and only `\textit` appearing monospaced). It would be great if this could be changed in two respects, making it more similar to code blocks that start with, e.g., `#+BEGIN_EXPORT latex`:

1. `@@latex:` and `@@` are greyed out;
2. the content (i.e. `\textit{something italic}`) is shown using the regular LaTeX font lock.

How can I get to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that my wishes can be fullfilled with this:

```
(font-lock-add-keywords 
 'org-mode
 '(("\\(@@latex:\\)\\(.*?\\)\\(@@\\)"
        (1 font-lock-comment-face)
        (2 '(org-latex-and-related))
        (3 font-lock-comment-face))
     ))
```

A reasonable alternative to `(org-latex-and-related)` would be `(org-block)`.